# Are complex functions plots possible in jsx graph?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

Suppose one attempts to plot  the complex valued function $f:\mathhbb{C} \to \mathhbb{C}$ as $f(z) =z$ in jsx graph. It may not be complicated as it appears. What one needs is two connected planes. The point (x, y) in domain planr gets mapped to the point (x, y) in codomain plane. As one drags point in domain plane,  corresponding changes takes place in the point in co domain plane. So the only question is how to connect two planes. It is matter of 2 dimensions only. If something similar to the following can be added to jsx graph, it would be great addition to jsx graph. Many properties of complex valued function can then be studied.
Here is the link. 
http://www.jimrolf.com/java/complexTool/bookComplexTool.html

Comment: Since jxsgraph is a library that can do interactive graphics, the answer to the question in your title is almost certainly "yes" (though of course possible doesn't mean easy). The rest of your question seems more like a feature request directed to the creators of jsxgraph than an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Two boards `board1`, `board2` can be connected with `board1.addChild(board2)`. This means, every update in `board1` triggers an update in `board2`.
Here is a basic example, see https://jsfiddle.net/zfbrsdwh/ :

```
const board1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox1', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});
var p = board1.create('point', [1,2], {name:'Drag me'});

const board2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox2', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});
var q  = board2.create('point', [function() { return [-p.Y(), p.X()]; }],
    {name:'image'});

board1.addChild(board2);
```

**Update in reply to the first comment:** Visualizing conformal maps in the complex plane can be done by applying the map to a quadrangle. It is necessary to define the edges of the quadrangle by a curve:

```
var p0 = board1.create('point', [2, -2]);
var p1 = board1.create('point', [2, 2]);
var p2 = board1.create('point', [-2, 2]);
var p3 = board1.create('point', [-2, -2]);

// Draw the quadrangle through p0, p1, p2, p3 as curve
// defined by [fx, fy]
var fx = function(x) {
    if (x < 0 || x > 4) { return NaN; }
    if (x < 1) {
        return (p1.X() - p0.X()) * x + p0.X();
    } else if (x < 2) {
        return (p2.X() - p1.X()) * (x - 1) + p1.X();
    } else if (x < 3) {
        return (p3.X() - p2.X()) * (x - 2) + p2.X();
    } else if (x < 4) {
        return (p0.X() - p3.X()) * (x - 3) + p3.X();
    }
  };

var fy = function(x) {
    if (x < 0 || x > 4) { return NaN; }
    if (x < 1) {
        return (p1.Y() - p0.Y()) * x + p0.Y();
    } else if (x < 2) {
        return (p2.Y() - p1.Y()) * (x - 1) + p1.Y();
    } else if (x < 3) {
        return (p3.Y() - p2.Y()) * (x - 2) + p2.Y();
    } else if (x < 4) {
        return (p0.Y() - p3.Y()) * (x - 3) + p3.Y();
    }
  };

var graph1 = board1.create('curve', [fx, fy, 0, 4]);
```

Then it should be easy to define a conformal map and plot the composition of the two maps in the second board:

```
// Conformal complex map z -> 1/z
var map = function(x, y) {
    var s = x*x+y*y;
    return [x / s, -y/s];
};

// Draw the image of the quadrangle under the map
f2x = function(x) {
    return map(fx(x), fy(x))[0];
};

f2y = function(x) {
    return map(fx(x), fy(x))[1];
};

var graph2 = board2.create('curve', [f2x, f2y, 0, 4]);
```

The full mathlet is at https://jsfiddle.net/Lmy60f4g/2/

Comment: Can rectangle dragging be possible instead of point? I mean there are rectangular regions on both planes which correspond to each other (instead of points)?

Comment: I don't know why the question got down votes though.